# C++ Vector pointer problems/Vector of pointers to a object in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

So, it seems that a lot of people new to C++ have problems with vectors, as their is a ton of questions about vector. I am not really new to C++ but I have never had this problem. Anyway, so my problem is with vector pointers. I am making a video game with a vector that holds the objects. It holds a reference to the objects so it can do collision response inside the collision function. To load the vector I used to do something like this:

```
Object a = Object(12, 135, 123, 124);
collision_rects.push_back(&a);
```

It worked perfectly like this, however I didn't want to type each individual object, so I made a function that read it from a text file, like this.

```
void get_from_file()
{ 
//Blah blah read numbers from file.
//then I would get the numbers and make a object from them.
Object a = Object(numbers from file);
collision_rects.push_back(&a);
}
```

But doing this didn't work! I fall through the floor! If I take the same data and load it the first way it works fine, but when I do it from a function in a text file it doesn't. I then realized that maybe it was because the Object went out of scope. So I tried making an object global then doing the same in the function, which worked. This is essentially the same as the first option but in a function. So I made two vectors, on the same scope so that the original object would not go out of scope like this.

```
std::vector<Object> objects;
void get_from_file()
{
//blah blah
objects[i] = Object(nums from file); //reading from numbers in a for loop
collision_rects.push_back(&objects[i]); //This throws weird
```

This didn't work either.(By the way, this is not even close to actual code, just a example of what the code does basically.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.
**EDIT**
So I don't know if I explained it perfectly, but I don't think its the problem that its pointing to a deleted object. That certainly would make it not work, however it is also another reason I believe.

`player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&uno);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&dos);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&tres);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&quatro);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&cinco);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&seis);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a8);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a9);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a10);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a11);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a12);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a13);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a14);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a15);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a16);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a17);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a18);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a19);
    player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&a20);`
Now this is my actual code that works. 
However when I do it like this, it doesn't work.

`objs.push_back(uno);
    objs.push_back(dos);
    objs.push_back(tres);
    objs.push_back(quatro);
    objs.push_back(cinco);
    objs.push_back(seis);
    objs.push_back(a8);
    objs.push_back(a9);
    objs.push_back(a10);
    objs.push_back(a11);
    objs.push_back(a12);
    objs.push_back(a13);
    objs.push_back(a14);
    objs.push_back(a15);
    objs.push_back(a16);
    objs.push_back(a17);
    objs.push_back(a18);
    objs.push_back(a19);
    objs.push_back(a20);
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.size(); i++)
    {
        //player->cHandler.objects.push_back(&objs[i]);
    }`
This is not working, and I don't know why.

Comment: `collision_rects.push_back(a);` Will work in all cases, provided you change your vector to not store pointers.

Comment: I kind of need it to store pointers so it can change the objects, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue has nothing to do with `std::vector`.  You only discovered the underlying problem by using `vector`, however you would have the very same problem if you returned a pointer to the object you created, or if you had a plain array and stored a pointer to the object in the array.

You're storing pointers to a local variable:

```
void get_from_file()
{ 
    Object a = Object(numbers from file);
    collision_rects.push_back(&a);
}
```

When the `get_from_file()` function returns, that `a` will be destroyed since it is a local object.  Your `collision_rects` vector will thus have a pointer to a variable that no longer exists.

The same issue would have occurred with this code:

```
Object* get_from_file()
{ 
    Object a = Object(numbers from file);
    return &a;  // returning pointer to local variable.  Bad.
}
```

So the solution is to make sure that the object's lifetime exists outside the `get_from_file` function.

You can either store objects in your vector (a `std::vector<Object>`), or if it must be pointer, it should be a pointer to an object that has a lifetime beyond the `get_from_file()` function.  That can be accomplished by allocating from the heap using `new`, or better yet, using a smart pointer type.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing a pointer to the objects, but the objects are then being destroyed so you're left with a pointer to nothing.

One good option is to store the objects themselves in the vector rather than the pointers.

Alternatively you could allocate an object on the heap (using e.g. `new Object(1, 2, 3)`) and store that pointer (that way the object isn't destroyed until you want it to be). If you do that I would recommend storing a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` - they do a lot of the work for you and make it easier to write correct code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok for you that objects in your `std::vector` get destroyed when `std::vector` is destoyed, store them in `std::vector<Object>`, and use `emplace_back` to construct them directly in the vector, without the need of temporary local variable:

```
std::vector<Object> collision_rects;
collision_rects.emplace_back(nums from file);
```